# WPF: RenderTransform applied after "spillover" content is chopped off

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

I have a control with this grid in it:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" MaxWidth="{x:Static local:PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH}">
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <DockPanel Width="{x:Static local:PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH}">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PlaybackButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <StackPanel.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" />
                </StackPanel.Effect>
                <Button x:Name="CornerRewind" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlFastBackward" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/FastBackBtn.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerStop" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlStop" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/StopBtn.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerPlay" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlPlay" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/PlayBtn.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerPause" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlPause" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/PauseBtn.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerFastForward" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlFastForward" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/FastFwdBtn.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerStepBack" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlBackAfewSec" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/BackAfewSecBtn.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CornerGoToLive" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlLive" >
                    <Image Source="/Pics/LiveBtn.png"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

What this XAML does is when it is placed in a container with Width >= PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH it displays the buttons in their original size, but when it is placed in a container with width < PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH, it scales the buttons down.

I wanted to achieve the same effect but in code. Don't ask me why - it'll take too long to explain.

So I removed the ViewBox and other elements that made it happen leaving this XAML:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="PlaybackButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <StackPanel.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" />
        </StackPanel.Effect>
        <Button x:Name="CornerRewind" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlFastBackward" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/FastBackBtn.png" />
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerStop" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlStop" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/StopBtn.png" />
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerPlay" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlPlay" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/PlayBtn.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerPause" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlPause" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/PauseBtn.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerFastForward" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlFastForward" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/FastFwdBtn.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerStepBack" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlBackAfewSec" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/BackAfewSecBtn.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CornerGoToLive" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CornerPlayerControlLive" >
            <Image Source="/Pics/LiveBtn.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And then I added the resize event handler:

```
    private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width < PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH)
        {
            double scale = e.NewSize.Width / PaneCtrl.MAX_NO_SCALE_WIDTH;
            PlaybackButtons.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale, PlaybackButtons.ActualWidth / 2, PlaybackButtons.ActualHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            PlaybackButtons.RenderTransform = null;
        }
    }
```

What I see is that it behaves in a similar way but when the container width is so small that some of the buttons in their original size would be chopped off (not shown) they are also not shown after I scale the StackPanel even though there should now be plenty of space to display them.

So naturally my question is why?

Probably because WPF first determines that they need to be hidden and then raises the SizeChanged event allowing me to scale them and does not "re-arrange" them after that.

Should I hook a different event or should I call something to force WPF to "re-arrange" or what?

Comment: P.S. I have since tried adding InvalidateArrange(); at the bottom of the Grid_SizeChanged and also moving the code in Grid_SizeChanged into protected override Size ArrangeOverride . In both cases the behavior remains the same (some buttons are still not displayed).

Comment: I now sort of understand why it does it. Inexplicably I was under impression that the container (Grid) is what's "chopping off" the ends of the PlayBackButtons, but it is actually PlayBackButtons itself (StackPanel) that does it. That is why hooking an earlier event or calling Arrange does not work. What might work is scaling the insides of the PlayBackButtons instead of the PlayBackButtons, but I still don't have a clean working way of doing it.